# How to update rendered content when my variable changes in Svelte/Svelte Kit

Tags: svelte, sveltekit

I have a simple svelte page in sveltekit:

```
<script>
    let array = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
</script>

{#each array as item}
    <li>{item}</li>
{/each}

<button
    on:click={() => {
        array.push('4');
        console.log(array);
    }}>Click Me</button
>
```

Pretty simple concept.  When I update my array, I want the content on the page to be updated as well.  Can someone help me on the road to figuring out what I need to do this?  Thanks IA!

PS-- The array is successfully updating on the button click

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Svelte's reactivity is triggered by assignments](https://svelte.dev/tutorial/updating-arrays-and-objects), so if you `push` to an array you must write `array = array` after it to tell the Svelte compiler it has changed.

**Example ([REPL](https://svelte.dev/repl/84f5330a2b824da2895e948b0918cdc7?version=3.55.0))**

```html
<script>
    let array = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
</script>

{#each array as item}
    <li>{item}</li>
{/each}

<button
    on:click={() => {
        array.push('4');
        array = array;
    }}
>
    Click Me
</button>
```

Comment: This is a bit verbose as you can do ```array = [...array, 4]```